# Which Java web framework is best if want to use jQuery

Tags: java, jquery, frameworks

I am very good at jQuery and have used it in many PHP websites.

Now I want to only choose that Web framework by which I can use jQuery to the same level as PHP, but in Java.

So, which web framework should I go for?

Comment: Wait, *what*? JQuery and Java have no relation, and to be honest, you sound like you have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: you make so sense, please clarify a bit.

Comment: Not sure how it matters. JQuery is a client side javascript framework, you can use it regardless of the server side framework.

Comment: i have read that jquery is easy to use with request/based frameworks rather than component based frameworks. is that true. thats why i asked that

Comment: @user564477 that's actually a pretty good question that demonstrates you understand what you're asking. That said, the implementation language has nothing to do with that.  I'd rephrase your question to focus on what you said in your comment.

Comment: @user That statement would need a lot more clarification before being answerable. Client-side Javascript/jQuery and server-side frameworks are so unrelated that it shouldn't really matter much though.

Comment: +1 - Although a little unclear, it's a great question.  Some frameworks force you to fight with the client side, while others aim to work with the client side concepts.

Comment: No reason for that many down votes, it's good question.

Comment: +1 because the question is currently negative for some reason; It seems perfectly reasonable that of the multiple frameworks available, one or two might have better JQuery support.

Comment: This is actually a really good question and certainly relevant to all web frameworks at the moment since JS usage on sites has exploded and is only going to increase which means that the web frameworks need to compensate.

Comment: +1 to counter the people who don't understand the question.  This question is meaningful and those who don't understand it should go elsewhere.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you already have heard, component based frameworks are a bit wonky when it comes to using certain JavaScript libraries. I have personally used only a few so I can't create a definite list of them. I do have, however, used both component and template based frameworks so I'd dare to say that I have at least somewhat educated opinion to express on the matter:

In general, **component based frameworks** are usually a bit harder to work with mainly since they integrate the "Ajax channel" to their own internals. As an example, the currently very popular [Apache Wicket](http://wicket.apache.org/) implements all of its Ajax stuff natively which, at times, does show as being broken on certain platforms et cetera. The reason for this integration usually is so that the developers of the framework can rely on the behaviour of the Ajax functions in their framework completely; by making a custom implementation, they can *lean* on it and potentially debug it faster. There are of course exceptions to this (*even Wicket has its own jQuery implementation called [wiQuery](http://code.google.com/p/wiquery/)*) but even then that integration may be subpar to what you would be able to write normally.

Now, **request based frameworks** as you call them (*I'd categorize them as template based frameworks based purely on my experience*) usually allow you to have more fine grained control over various parts of the page, usually you end up even writing the final markup with some magic tags here and there for linking the dynamic part of the web application with the static layout. With this in mind, it's rather obvious that these usually allow you as a developer to choose - among a lot of other things - the JavaScript library of your choice, but it's a trade-off; whatever the component based framework would provide at this point is something you need to reimplement by yourself. Most commonly this is limited to handling Ajax requests but that varies from framework to framework.

**To summarize**, if you really want to use jQuery (*and why wouldn't you*) and you can't agree with the way it has been integrated in component based frameworks, look what the other kind has to offer.

---

If I had to recommend something that I would believe would fit you perfectly, I'd recommend [GSP](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html) on top of [Spring MVC](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/mvc.html) using plain Java for backend stuff and such, but this combination doesn't actually even exist since GSP is the view part of [Grails](http://grails.org/), a [Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/) based web application framework.

Answer (score 5):

For Java, I would suggest Spring's REST framework, where you can use JSON in your requests and your response.  By using JSON to return your data back to the client side, you could use JQuery to parse the JSON, manipulate the data, and then manipulate the HTML document programmatically.

The advantage of this method is that it makes it easier to keep your content, behavior, and presentation separate.  If you're working on a project with a design team of varying programming backgrounds, and if your HTML/CSS skills aren't as good as theirs, this method can be very powerful for maintaining a separation of concern.

Other than that, any framework could work, as JavaScript and server-side languages run in completely different environments.

Comment: is REST and Spring MVC different

Comment: @user564477: REST in SpringMVC is just another view to the underlying dynamic data; by doing what jmort253 suggests, you can create a rich web application entirely on top of Spring just as he describes.

Answer (score 1):

You mean which MVC framework? It shouldn't matter. JQuery or any other Javascript framework is independent of what Java Framework you use.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend grails (without scaffolding, and without main layout: design your own layout using css and jquery (validation, date-picker and stuffs)), but since it uses objects a lot sometimes your application can run out of memory and you would require to allocate large memory. You can't avoid some of the places where you might not want those heavy stuffs(since every declaration creates getter and setter implicitly), but application development in grails is very fast, you will have a habit of using cool things as versioning in current data (but if you have transactions, then why do you need those, I don't know), if you don't want to get into the nuisance of scaffolding, but still want to see it as a reference then you can have two copies(one code generated from scaffolding) and other without it, so that you can develop your own version with carefully crafting the application with a reference to the scaffolded version. You should definitely give it a try before using 50 unrelated things in java(always nuisance) to just develop a simple web site.